# Can I close all Outlook.com sessions that I have opened on different computers?

Tags: session, hotmail, outlook.com

It would seem that I forgot to logout of my Hotmail account (on [Outlook.com](http://outlook.com/) aka [Login.live.com](https://login.live.com)) on a comptuer at school.

Someone used this conenction to send unwanted e-mail.

Even though I changed the password, this other session still appears valid since the person can still send e-mail.

Can I remotely shut this session down (something similar to *disconnect from everywhere*) ?

Comment: Log in, then visit 
https://account.live.com/securityprivacy/overview . From here you can see recent sign ins, manage advance security and change the password

Answer (score 3):

You cannot invalidate the sessions remotely. However changing password helps. I am not sure how long would that take to get into effect.

You can review your activities here: https://account.live.com/Activity

Some security related options here: https://account.microsoft.com/security

Answer (score 0):

Log in, then visit:
https://account.live.com/Activity
here you can see recent sign in activity

Comment: OP is asking how to Logout!